# Unexpected Character(#) error in angular5 with ansi-html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When i fire ng serve --open command then its showing error like below mentioned in command prompt.

> ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'
>   (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> > ## !/bin/sh | basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')") | i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.

Output:

```
Cannot GET /
```

If I remove that ansi-html file from my build I'm not getting any error and working fine, but is it right way to do run my application without ansi-html file ?

After removing ansi-html file my application output.

[after removing ansi-htmlfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXOLu.png)

Comment: Generated  with angular-cli and I have this these lines ofcode in that file

#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/ansi-html/bin/ansi-html" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/ansi-html/bin/ansi-html" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret

Answer (score 0):

Use npm module 
link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-html

**Installation**

```
npm install ansi-html
```

**Usage**

```
var ansiHTML = require('ansi-html');
var str = ansiHTML('[ANSI_TEXT]');
```

Comment: ansi-html file generated by default with angular-cli. do I need to install again with npm ?

Comment: Yes install it via npm and use it as per your usage.

Comment: Thanks, codereverb. my code is working,  if I delete that ansi-html file.